# Confusion about adjoint of $\nabla$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Consider $\nabla: H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)^n$. It is a bounded linear operator.
Consider its Hilbert adjoint  $\nabla^*: L^2(\Omega)^n \to H^1(\Omega)$, i.e. for $V \in L^2(\Omega)^n$
$$
\langle \phi, \nabla^* V \rangle_{H^1(\Omega)} := \langle \nabla \phi, V \rangle_{L^2(\Omega)^n} \quad \forall\phi\in H^1(\Omega)
$$
What is $\nabla^*$? It is not $-\mathrm{div}$, which would be the case if we were considering $\nabla: H^1(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)^n$ as an unbounded operator.

Comment: A first comment I would make, is that if you identify $\mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)$ with its dual, then you can no longer identify $\mathrm{H}^1(\Omega)$ with its dual.

Therefore, the dual operator is $$\nabla^\ast\,:\,\mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)^n \longrightarrow (\mathrm{H}^1(\Omega))^\ast.$$

And this is just the standard distributional (negative) divergence operator, that is $\nabla^\ast = - \mathrm{div}$.

Moreover, notice that if $\Omega$ is nice enough, say a (bounded) Lipschitz domain at least, then one has $$(\mathrm{H}^1(\Omega))^\ast \simeq \mathrm{H}^{-1}_0(\Omega).$$

Comment: If you identify the duals of $L^2$ and of $H^1$ with $L^2$ and $H^1$, you have to take care of the associated Riesz isomorphisms, and you end up with $\nabla^*V = (-\Delta)^{-1} div(V)$.